# errno=13. Unable to start due to shared memory failure

Tags: httpd, selinux, mod-jk, tomcat8

I have integrated httpd with tomcat by help of mod_Jk. In this case, selinux is enforcing condition.

Due to enforcing enable in Selinux that's why I am unable to run the httpd in our linux server(centos 7). I am facing given issue " **errno=13. Unable to start due to shared memory failure.**" in /var/log/httpd/error_log

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
 Do allow this access for now by executing:

# grep httpd /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol

# semodule -i mypol.pp